# How to implement a notification system?

Tags: mysql, notifications

I've made a system of posts and comments and now I would add a notification system to alert each user in the conversation each time someone write a comment.

My question is which is the best way in terms of database for build this system?
I thought to a notifications table with the following fields:

```
id_notification | sent_by | id_user_receiver | id_post
      1              2             3              10
```

In this example the user with id 2 have wrote a comment to the post with id 10 and the user with id 3 receive the notification. But, if the conversation involves 100 or 1000 users, each time some user write on the conversation I'll end having 100 or 1000 records in the database. I think is not the right way. What is a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the right way, if the user read the notification you can simply delete the row, since it's not necessary anymore in the future. And besides that, 1000 records is nothing. You can easily have millions of records in your tables, just ensure your indexes are right.

Answer (score 0):

First step is create a new model and controller for notification

```
   $ rails g model Notification  post:references comment:references user:references read:boolean

   $ rake db:migrate
   $ rails g controller Notifications index
```

Once this is done, the next step is add the has_many :notifications to the User, Post, and Comment models.

Once this is done, add  the following code to the Comments model:

```
       after_create :create_notification

       private

         def create_notification
           @post = Post.find_by(self.post_id)
           @user = User.find_by(@post.user_id).id
             Notification.create(
             post_id: self.post_id,
            user_id: @user,
             comment_id: self,
             read: false
              )
        end
```

The above snippet create a notification once a comment is created.
The next step is to edit the Notifications controller so that a notification can be deleted and a user can mark the notification as read:

```
       def index
         @notifications = current_user.notications
         @notifications.each do |notification|
         notification.update_attribute(:checked, true)
      end
     end

      def destroy
        @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
        @notification.destroy
        redirect_to :back
      end
```

Next Thing to do is set up a way to delete the notification when a comment is deleted:

```
          def destroy
           @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
           @notification = Notification.where(:comment_id => @comment.id)
             if @notification.nil?
               @notification.destroy
             end
           @comment.destroy
           redirect_to :back
        end
```

Last thing to do is create some views. You can do what ever you want